# PHP not parsed using apache2 and php-fpm

Tags: apache, vagrant, php, puphpet

Earlier today I destroyed my vagrant box and uploaded a slightly modified version of my config.yaml (increased memory and mailcatcher). However for some reason the php is just displayed on the screen when running the index file instead of being interpreted.

Can't seem to figure out what's going on. At the end of `vagrant up` I am greeted by 2 friendly elephants so the setup seems to have worked. Just the php interpretation is messing

My config.yaml is generated by puphpet.com

config.yaml:

```
vagrantfile-local:
    vm:
        box: puphpet/debian75-x64
        box_url: puphpet/debian75-x64
        hostname: ''
        memory: '2048'
        cpus: '1'
        chosen_provider: virtualbox
        network:
            private_network: 192.168.56.101
            forwarded_port:
                vI4EQBlkqIQn:
                    host: '4567'
                    guest: '22'
        post_up_message: ''
        provider:
            virtualbox:
                modifyvm:
                    natdnshostresolver1: on
            vmware:
                numvcpus: 1
            parallels:
                cpus: 1
        provision:
            puppet:
                manifests_path: puphpet/puppet
                manifest_file: site.pp
                module_path: puphpet/puppet/modules
                options:
                    - '--verbose'
                    - '--hiera_config /vagrant/puphpet/puppet/hiera.yaml'
                    - '--parser future'
        synced_folder:
            MCoX8xNepCXZ:
                source: 'd:/Projects'
                target: /var/www
                sync_type: default
                rsync:
                    auto: 'false'
        usable_port_range:
            start: 10200
            stop: 10500
    ssh:
        host: null
        port: null
        private_key_path: null
        username: vagrant
        guest_port: null
        keep_alive: true
        forward_agent: false
        forward_x11: false
        shell: 'bash -l'
    vagrant:
        host: detect
server:
    install: '1'
    packages:
        - vim
        - nano
        - php5-curl
        - php5-imagick
        - php5-gd
firewall:
    install: '1'
    rules: null
apache:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        user: www-data
        group: www-data
        default_vhost: true
        manage_user: false
        manage_group: false
        sendfile: 0
    modules:
        - rewrite
        - deflate
        - cache
    vhosts:
        UgZbGbCkwGyD:
            servername: exo-l.dev
            serveraliases:
                - www.exo-l.dev
            docroot: /var/www/exo
            port: '80'
            setenv:
                - 'APP_ENV dev'
            override:
                - All
            options:
                - Indexes
                - FollowSymLinks
                - MultiViews
            engine: php
            custom_fragment: ''
            ssl_cert: ''
            ssl_key: ''
            ssl_chain: ''
            ssl_certs_dir: ''
    mod_pagespeed: 0
nginx:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        default_vhost: 1
        proxy_buffer_size: 128k
        proxy_buffers: '4 256k'
    vhosts:
        u7vBLPXfNEGJ:
            server_name: awesome.dev
            server_aliases:
                - www.awesome.dev
            www_root: /var/www/awesome.dev
            listen_port: '80'
            location: .php$
            index_files:
                - index.html
                - index.htm
                - index.php
            envvars:
                - 'APP_ENV dev'
            engine: php
            ssl_cert: ''
            ssl_key: ''
php:
    install: '1'
    version: '54'
    composer: '1'
    composer_home: ''
    modules:
        php:
            - cli
            - intl
            - mcrypt
        pear: {  }
        pecl:
            - pecl_http
    ini:
        display_errors: On
        session.save_path: /var/lib/php/session
        error_reporting: '-1'
    timezone: Europe/Amsterdam
    mod_php: 0
hhvm:
    install: '0'
    nightly: 0
    composer: '1'
    composer_home: ''
    settings:
        host: '0'
        port: '0'
    ini: {  }
    timezone: null
xdebug:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        xdebug.default_enable: '1'
        xdebug.remote_autostart: '0'
        xdebug.remote_connect_back: '1'
        xdebug.remote_enable: '1'
        xdebug.remote_handler: dbgp
        xdebug.remote_port: '9000'
xhprof:
    install: '0'
drush:
    install: '0'
    version: ''
ruby:
    install: '1'
    versions: {  }
nodejs:
    install: '0'
    npm_packages: {  }
python:
    install: '1'
    packages: {  }
    versions: {  }
mysql:
    install: '1'
    root_password: 
    adminer: '1'
    databases:
        Hx0jI5fJIeSV:
            grant:
                - ALL
            name: exo
            host: localhost
            user: ortix
            password: 
            sql_file: ''
postgresql:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        root_password: '123'
        user_group: postgres
        encoding: UTF8
        version: '9.3'
    databases: {  }
    adminer: 0
mariadb:
    install: '0'
    root_password: '123'
    adminer: 0
    databases: {  }
    version: '10.0'
sqlite:
    install: '0'
    adminer: 0
    databases: {  }
mongodb:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        auth: 1
        port: '27017'
    databases: {  }
redis:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        conf_port: '6379'
mailcatcher:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        smtp_ip: 0.0.0.0
        smtp_port: 1025
        http_ip: 0.0.0.0
        http_port: '1080'
        mailcatcher_path: /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/default
        from_email_method: inline
beanstalkd:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        listenaddress: 0.0.0.0
        listenport: '13000'
        maxjobsize: '65535'
        maxconnections: '1024'
        binlogdir: /var/lib/beanstalkd/binlog
        binlogfsync: null
        binlogsize: '10485760'
    beanstalk_console: 0
    binlogdir: /var/lib/beanstalkd/binlog
rabbitmq:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        port: '5672'
elastic_search:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        java_install: true
        autoupgrade: true
```

vagrant file:

```
require 'yaml'

dir = File.dirname(File.expand_path(__FILE__))

configValues = YAML.load_file("#{dir}/puphpet/config.yaml")
data         = configValues['vagrantfile-local']

Vagrant.require_version '>= 1.6.0'

Vagrant.configure('2') do |config|
  config.vm.box     = "#{data['vm']['box']}"
  config.vm.box_url = "#{data['vm']['box_url']}"

  if data['vm']['hostname'].to_s.strip.length != 0
    config.vm.hostname = "#{data['vm']['hostname']}"
  end

  if data['vm']['network']['private_network'].to_s != ''
    config.vm.network 'private_network', ip: "#{data['vm']['network']['private_network']}"
  end

  data['vm']['network']['forwarded_port'].each do |i, port|
    if port['guest'] != '' && port['host'] != ''
      config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: port['guest'].to_i, host: port['host'].to_i
    end
  end

  if !data['vm']['post_up_message'].nil?
    config.vm.post_up_message = "#{data['vm']['post_up_message']}"
  end

  if Vagrant.has_plugin?('vagrant-hostmanager')
    hosts = Array.new()

    if !configValues['apache']['install'].nil? &&
        configValues['apache']['install'].to_i == 1 &&
        configValues['apache']['vhosts'].is_a?(Hash)
      configValues['apache']['vhosts'].each do |i, vhost|
        hosts.push(vhost['servername'])

        if vhost['serveraliases'].is_a?(Array)
          vhost['serveraliases'].each do |vhost_alias|
            hosts.push(vhost_alias)
          end
        end
      end
    elsif !configValues['nginx']['install'].nil? &&
           configValues['nginx']['install'].to_i == 1 &&
           configValues['nginx']['vhosts'].is_a?(Hash)
      configValues['nginx']['vhosts'].each do |i, vhost|
        hosts.push(vhost['server_name'])

        if vhost['server_aliases'].is_a?(Array)
          vhost['server_aliases'].each do |x, vhost_alias|
            hosts.push(vhost_alias)
          end
        end
      end
    end

    if hosts.any?
      contents = File.open("#{dir}/puphpet/shell/ascii-art/hostmanager-notice.txt", 'r'){ |file| file.read }
      puts "\n\033[32m#{contents}\033[0m\n"

      if config.vm.hostname.to_s.strip.length == 0
        config.vm.hostname = 'puphpet-dev-machine'
      end

      config.hostmanager.enabled           = true
      config.hostmanager.manage_host       = true
      config.hostmanager.ignore_private_ip = false
      config.hostmanager.include_offline   = false
      config.hostmanager.aliases           = hosts
    end
  end

  if Vagrant.has_plugin?('vagrant-cachier')
    config.cache.scope = :box
  end

  data['vm']['synced_folder'].each do |i, folder|
    if folder['source'] != '' && folder['target'] != ''
      if folder['sync_type'] == 'nfs'
        config.vm.synced_folder "#{folder['source']}", "#{folder['target']}", id: "#{i}", type: 'nfs'
      elsif folder['sync_type'] == 'smb'
        config.vm.synced_folder "#{folder['source']}", "#{folder['target']}", id: "#{i}", type: 'smb'
      elsif folder['sync_type'] == 'rsync'
        rsync_args = !folder['rsync']['args'].nil? ? folder['rsync']['args'] : ['--verbose', '--archive', '-z']
        rsync_auto = !folder['rsync']['auto'].nil? ? folder['rsync']['auto'] : true
        rsync_exclude = !folder['rsync']['exclude'].nil? ? folder['rsync']['exclude'] : ['.vagrant/']

        config.vm.synced_folder "#{folder['source']}", "#{folder['target']}", id: "#{i}",
          rsync__args: rsync_args, rsync__exclude: rsync_exclude, rsync__auto: rsync_auto, type: 'rsync'
      else
        config.vm.synced_folder "#{folder['source']}", "#{folder['target']}", id: "#{i}",
          group: 'www-data', owner: 'www-data', mount_options: ['dmode=775', 'fmode=764']
      end
    end
  end

  config.vm.usable_port_range = (data['vm']['usable_port_range']['start'].to_i..data['vm']['usable_port_range']['stop'].to_i)

  if data['vm']['chosen_provider'].empty? || data['vm']['chosen_provider'] == 'virtualbox'
    ENV['VAGRANT_DEFAULT_PROVIDER'] = 'virtualbox'

    config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |virtualbox|
      data['vm']['provider']['virtualbox']['modifyvm'].each do |key, value|
        if key == 'memory'
          next
        end
        if key == 'cpus'
          next
        end

        if key == 'natdnshostresolver1'
          value = value ? 'on' : 'off'
        end

        virtualbox.customize ['modifyvm', :id, "--#{key}", "#{value}"]
      end

      virtualbox.customize ['modifyvm', :id, '--memory', "#{data['vm']['memory']}"]
      virtualbox.customize ['modifyvm', :id, '--cpus', "#{data['vm']['cpus']}"]

      if data['vm']['hostname'].to_s.strip.length != 0
        virtualbox.customize ['modifyvm', :id, '--name', config.vm.hostname]
      end
    end
  end

  if data['vm']['chosen_provider'] == 'vmware_fusion' || data['vm']['chosen_provider'] == 'vmware_workstation'
    ENV['VAGRANT_DEFAULT_PROVIDER'] = (data['vm']['chosen_provider'] == 'vmware_fusion') ? 'vmware_fusion' : 'vmware_workstation'

    config.vm.provider 'vmware_fusion' do |v|
      data['vm']['provider']['vmware'].each do |key, value|
        if key == 'memsize'
          next
        end
        if key == 'cpus'
          next
        end

        v.vmx["#{key}"] = "#{value}"
      end

      v.vmx['memsize']  = "#{data['vm']['memory']}"
      v.vmx['numvcpus'] = "#{data['vm']['cpus']}"

      if data['vm']['hostname'].to_s.strip.length != 0
        v.vmx['displayName'] = config.vm.hostname
      end
    end
  end

  if data['vm']['chosen_provider'] == 'parallels'
    ENV['VAGRANT_DEFAULT_PROVIDER'] = 'parallels'

    config.vm.provider 'parallels' do |v|
      data['vm']['provider']['parallels'].each do |key, value|
        if key == 'memsize'
          next
        end
        if key == 'cpus'
          next
        end

        v.customize ['set', :id, "--#{key}", "#{value}"]
      end

      v.memory = "#{data['vm']['memory']}"
      v.cpus   = "#{data['vm']['cpus']}"

      if data['vm']['hostname'].to_s.strip.length != 0
        v.name = config.vm.hostname
      end
    end
  end

  ssh_username = !data['ssh']['username'].nil? ? data['ssh']['username'] : 'vagrant'

  config.vm.provision 'shell' do |s|
    s.path = 'puphpet/shell/initial-setup.sh'
    s.args = '/vagrant/puphpet'
  end
  config.vm.provision 'shell' do |kg|
    kg.path = 'puphpet/shell/ssh-keygen.sh'
    kg.args = "#{ssh_username}"
  end
  config.vm.provision :shell, :path => 'puphpet/shell/install-ruby.sh'
  config.vm.provision :shell, :path => 'puphpet/shell/install-puppet.sh'

  config.vm.provision :puppet do |puppet|
    puppet.facter = {
      'ssh_username'     => "#{ssh_username}",
      'provisioner_type' => ENV['VAGRANT_DEFAULT_PROVIDER'],
      'vm_target_key'    => 'vagrantfile-local',
    }
    puppet.manifests_path = "#{data['vm']['provision']['puppet']['manifests_path']}"
    puppet.manifest_file  = "#{data['vm']['provision']['puppet']['manifest_file']}"
    puppet.module_path    = "#{data['vm']['provision']['puppet']['module_path']}"

    if !data['vm']['provision']['puppet']['options'].empty?
      puppet.options = data['vm']['provision']['puppet']['options']
    end
  end

  config.vm.provision :shell do |s|
    s.path = 'puphpet/shell/execute-files.sh'
    s.args = ['exec-once', 'exec-always']
  end
  config.vm.provision :shell, run: 'always' do |s|
    s.path = 'puphpet/shell/execute-files.sh'
    s.args = ['startup-once', 'startup-always']
  end
  config.vm.provision :shell, :path => 'puphpet/shell/important-notices.sh'

  if File.file?("#{dir}/puphpet/files/dot/ssh/id_rsa")
    config.ssh.private_key_path = [
      "#{dir}/puphpet/files/dot/ssh/id_rsa",
      "#{dir}/puphpet/files/dot/ssh/insecure_private_key"
    ]
  end

  if !data['ssh']['host'].nil?
    config.ssh.host = "#{data['ssh']['host']}"
  end
  if !data['ssh']['port'].nil?
    config.ssh.port = "#{data['ssh']['port']}"
  end
  if !data['ssh']['username'].nil?
    config.ssh.username = "#{data['ssh']['username']}"
  end
  if !data['ssh']['guest_port'].nil?
    config.ssh.guest_port = data['ssh']['guest_port']
  end
  if !data['ssh']['shell'].nil?
    config.ssh.shell = "#{data['ssh']['shell']}"
  end
  if !data['ssh']['keep_alive'].nil?
    config.ssh.keep_alive = data['ssh']['keep_alive']
  end
  if !data['ssh']['forward_agent'].nil?
    config.ssh.forward_agent = data['ssh']['forward_agent']
  end
  if !data['ssh']['forward_x11'].nil?
    config.ssh.forward_x11 = data['ssh']['forward_x11']
  end
  if !data['vagrant']['host'].nil?
    config.vagrant.host = data['vagrant']['host'].gsub(':', '').intern
  end
end
```

```

Comment: This is likely to be related to apache and php-fpm config rather than anything Vagrant specific. You should check that apache and php-fpm are configured correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing two critical sections to your Apache configuration in your `config.yaml` file.  The **Directory Block** and a **FilesMatch** block must be present.  The answer given by PuPHPet's own author to another similar question will fix this problem; see:  [Php not interpreted by apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30235886/php-not-interpreted-by-apache/30242652#30242652).